# Is "typedef" in between the type and the alias standard-conformant?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, typedef

I stumbled upon some code where the `typedef` keyword is in between the type and the alias name like in

```
int typedef INT;
```

It compiles in gcc and clang ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/125cb85906a0f51f)). I am not very good in understanding standardese. So my question is: Is this standard conformant? Can I rely on compilers to support it?

Comment: why not adopt the real standard to help with future coding with your code?

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @DanielA.White: The C or C++ standards are not known for easy legibility.

Comment: help with readability and maintainability.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf page 166.

Comment: @DanielA.White The Standard is not *meant* to be readable. It is meant to be *precise*.

Comment: @BoBTFish im not talking about the standard, i'm talking about the OPs code.

Comment: @JameyD That doesn't really help. The difficulty is in *interpreting* this text.

Comment: @DanielA.White I still don't understand. The question is clearly whether or not this is Standard-conforming, not if it is more or less readable than some other form (which would probably be off topic anyway).

Comment: English is not the most precise language and we see that failing here twice. It's hard to interpret the Standard written in it AND it's hard to interpret the use of the word standard in comments discussing the Standard. One could almost see the Monty Python sketch or the Abbot and Costello banter.

Comment: @BoBTFish I posted it as shortcut. Not really as an answer.

Comment: @user4581301: You might confuse standard with norm. Both terms are well-defined. For German readers: Both words are perfect false friends in English vs. German.

Comment: Get's a bit worse than that, unfortunately. The meaning of standard as a noun (a level, measure, or ranking) is different from standard as an adjective (very similar to norm's definition when used as a noun) and different again from standard as in the C++ Standard. It appears the top comment used the adjective version in a noun context and tacked on "the real", leading readers, myself included, to infer the poster spoke of the C++ Standard and not the standard, as in typical, usage of `typedef`. I propose instead of two "standard"s, we replace one usage with "ozglewit" to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL/DR Version**

Yes, `int typedef INT` is conforming.

**James Michener Version**

C declaration syntax ([C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> **6.7 Declarations**
> **Syntax**
> 1    `declaration:`
>         `declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;`
>         `static_assert-declaration`
>     `declaration-specifiers:`
>         `storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt`
>         `type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt`
>         `type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt`
>         `function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt`
>         `alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt`
> ...

What this says is that in a single declaration you can have a sequence of one or more *declaration specifiers*, where each declaration specifier can be a storage class specifier (`auto`, `extern`, `static`, `typedef`), a type specifier (`int`, `float`, `char`, etc.), a type qualifier (`const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, etc.), a function specifier (`inline`), or an alignment specifier.

The order in which various specifiers appear doesn't matter; `static const short int x;` may be written as `int static short const x`, or `int short const static x`, etc.  As a matter of practice, most people put the storage class specifier first, then any function or alignment specifiers (if necessary), then any type qualifiers, then type specifiers, so `static const short int x` is how *most* people would write that declaration.

This syntax is what allows us to write types like `long double` or `long long` or `unsigned long int`, etc.

Note that while the *syntax* allows arbitrary (and arbitrarily long) sequences of type specifiers, there's a semantic rule that only allows a relative few.  You can't write `short short short short x`, for example, or `long long long double y`.  Only the following sequences are allowed:

> **Constraints**
> 2    At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
> and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
> type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there
> is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
> intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.
>         — `void`
>         — `char`
>         — `signed char`
>         — `unsigned char`
>         — `short, signed short, short int, or signed short int`
>         — `unsigned short, or unsigned short int`
>         — `int, signed, or signed int`
>         — `unsigned, or unsigned int`
>         — `long, signed long, long int, or signed long int`
>         — `unsigned long, or unsigned long int`
>         — `long long, signed long long, long long int, or`
>             `signed long long int`
>         — `unsigned long long, or unsigned long long int`
>         — `float`
>         — `double`
>         — `long double`
>         — `_Bool`
>         — `float _Complex`
>         — `double _Complex`
>         — `long double _Complex`
>         — atomic type specifier
>         — struct or union specifier
>         — enum specifier
>         — typedef name

**Addendum**

As Keith points out in the comment below, a future revision of the language may limit storage class specifiers to the beginning of the declaration, so `int typedef INT` may not be legal under a future compiler.

Comment: Yes -- but the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.11.5 (Future language directions) says: "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.", so at least in principle a future C standard might not permit `int typedef INT;`. Feel free to add this to your answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Done.

Answer (score 25):

The `typedef` keyword is classified as a storage class specifier in C, though the standard explicitly remarks that that's for convenience in expressing the formal language syntax.  It nevertheless follows that `typedef` can appear in exactly the same places that any other storage class specifier, such as `extern` or `static`, can appear.  [C2011, 6.7.1/5]

In fact, the syntax allows storage-class specifiers to be intermixed with type specifiers, type qualifiers, and other "declaration specifiers" in declarations.  [C2011, 6.7/1, 6.7/6]

Thus, yes, it is valid to put the `typedef` keyword after the type name, as in your example.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at 7.1/1 you see this grammar for `decl-specifier:`, which shows that a `type-specifier` and the `typedef` keyword fall at the same point in the grammar, allowing you to interchange them as in the question (although as an aside never write code like this, it's not idiomatic at all).

> decl-specifier:
>
> ```
> storage-class-specifier
>
> type-specifier
>
> function-specifier
>
> friend
>
> typedef
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I compile using:

gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99

In the background, this means `-Wold-style-declaration` is set.

Then the compiler outputs the following warning message:

```
warning: 'typedef' is not a beginning of declaration [-Wold-style-declaration]
```

without that parameter being set, the compiler handles the syntax with no problems

So the posted syntax is within the standard, but can be confusing to the reader.

Answer (score -2):

```
typedef int INT
```

> RightWay to use typedef
>
> Wherever you use INT it will be replace by int datatype
>
> This main purpose is to only for long data string to simple value but in this case you can use normal int itself
>
> You can relay on just for test purpose use debugging you can understand very well