# Can we place "typedef" specifier anywhere in the declaration?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, typedef, storage-class-specifier

The syntax of `typedef` specifier :

```
typedef <existing_name> <alias_name>
```

for example:

```
typedef long unsigned int Int;
```

It's working fine.

But, If I place `typedef` anywhere in the declaration, Like this:

```
long unsigned typedef int Int;
```

Then, It's also working fine.

**Why? Can we place `typedef` anywhere in the declaration?**

Comment: why not? `int short static someVar;` is also valid, right?

Comment: Because the C standard specifies that. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Good but no good, you could have googled something like "typedef declaration ordering". -Edit NVM you need to know `typedef` is a "storage-class" to find the dupe effectively.

Comment: C standard says that *on a syntactic point of view* `typedef` is just a storage class specifier like `extern` or `static`, so it can be intermixed with the type declarator.

Comment: @rsp Please do not put language tags on question title, there are tags fields dedicated for that purpose.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35228738/3876684)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**First of all**, quoting from §6.11.5, "Future language directions"

> 1 The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

So, *do not* rely on this, as it may be removed in the future.

---

That said, to understand why this works, check the C11 standard, chapter §6.7.2:

> [...] the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

From §6.7.1, we know `typedef` is a storage-class specifier (one particular sort of a declaration specifier), so it can be placed after (or before) the type specifier (*i.e.*, can be intermixed). It does not change anything.

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed allowed by the C standard. `typedef` is a *storage class specifier* and if you look at the grammar given in the C standard (N1570, latest draft for C11, **§6.7 p1**):

> **Syntax**
>   *declaration:*
>   .    *declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list*(opt) ;
>   .    *static_assert-declaration*
>   *declaration-specifiers:*
>   .    *storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers*(opt)
>   .    *type-specifier declaration-specifiers*(opt)
>   .    *type-qualifier declaration-specifiers*(opt)
>   .    *function-specifier declaration-specifiers*(opt)
>   .    *alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers*(opt)
>   *init-declarator-list:*
>   .    *init-declarator*
>   .    *init-declarator-list , init-declarator*
>   *init-declarator:*
>   .    *declarator*
>   .    *declarator = initializer*

the *storage class specifier* can appear *after* other *declaration specifiers* like the *type specifier*.

But **you shouldn't use it**, it's obsolescent, see **§6.11.5**:

> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.